# Square on a lattice

Tags: combinatorics

> A square whose side length is $2$ is placed on a lattice. If it covers not less than $7$ lattice points, how many lattice points does it really cover? (Lattice points on its boundary are considered to be covered)

The diagonal, which is the greatest span of the square, equals to $2\sqrt2$, and $2\sqrt2<3$, so the square can’t cover lattice points of $4$ different $x$ coordinates or $y$ coordinates.

In addition, since the square doesn’t have holes in it, if it covers lattice points $A,B$, it must also cover any lattice point on segment $AB$.

From the two analyses above, we see that the $7$ lattice points must be exactly on $3$ different rows and columns, and they must be arranged like

[image]

For the rest of the solution I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once we know that the covered points must fit into a $3×3$ grid of $9$ points, if the covered points include a pair $a,b$ of diagonally opposite points of the grid, one of the large square's diagonals must coincide with the segment $a,b$, fixing it in a position where it covers all $9$ points of the grid. This leaves (up to rotation/reflection) one case to consider, the left arrangement in your question.

Since the large square covers six points that form two small squares of side length $1$, the small squares may be viewed as *packed* in the large square. Any packing of two squares of side $1$ into one of side $2$ must be axis-aligned (see Theorem 1 in [Friedman's square-packing paper](https://erich-friedman.github.io/papers/squares/squares.html) for the proof). So the large square is axis-aligned, and since it also contains the seventh point it must in fact have its corners coincide with the grid's corners and cover all the latter's $9$ points.

This completes the proof that the large square covers $9$ points if it covers at least $7$.

Comment: I didn’t understand why $P=\{(1,1)\}$ being unavoidable suffices to prove theorem 1.

Comment: @youthdoo Please read the paper carefully.